# How to dynamically send category, cation, label and value to Analytics via Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have managed to create an event to register data on my Google Analytics account with Google Tag Manager. But I can't set any information dynamically.

Here is my current setting:
[image]

I'm firing this event with:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'event_name'});
```

The event is working fine, my data is being registered at Google Analytics, but I can't overwrite "My Category", "My action" and "My Label", "My Value".

Pretty much like Google Analytics used to do with:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'My Category', 'My Action');
```

It was very easy to set any value to and fire an event, but now I am confused on how to do it via Google Tag Manager.

What would be the best way to send any value to these fields? Or I need to create a tag for each event I want to fire (that would not make any sense)?

Comment: Category, Action, Label can be hard values that you can input as text or click on + sign and add variables eg {{clicktext}}
It would populate as event data. 

Did you add trigger to fire event?

You should also debug using Preview option in Google Tag Manager. It shows you on click, what are the variables passed in datalayer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on where you are acquiring the event parameters from. Are they coming from text that is being clicked, or are they coming from the page path, etc. One possible solution would require that you push your dynamic category, action, label values with your dataLayer push:

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'event_name',
   'category': 'your category',
   'action': 'your action',
   'label': 'your label'
})
```

In GTM, you would then need to define new dataLayer variables that would correspond to the category, action, and label. In your event tag, you would then just use the new dataLayer variables.